# error in PDO connection

Tags: php

Hye, kindly need your help to assist me finding the error of this connection. The reason is that i didn't get submitting the data in a form to the database.

```
<?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: You haven't stated your database name

Comment: oh i remove for a while that db name

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the database name.

`dbname=`You Forgot The Name Here;

P.S. if you don't want to include the database, you should leave the entire part.

Comment: oh i remove for a while that db name, can you show me how to change the connection to mysqli? using $bdd

Comment: $bdd = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); That should be it I think.

Comment: is it true my coding --> $bdd = mysql_select_db('',mysql_connect('localhost','root',''));

Comment: No, but do you want to use mysqli or mysql?
By using mysql it looks like this:
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('dbname'); <-- this is optional

with mysqli it is:
$bdd = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',''); <-- you can add another parameter with the database name, but this is optional.

Comment: i'm using mysql, $bdd = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); mysql_select_db('dbname'); and still contain the error

Comment: basically, im using $bdd as my declaration before execute the connection

Comment: 'dbname' should be **your** database name

Comment: error :( $bdd = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 mysql_select_db('epayment');

Comment: Then I advide you to take a further look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)